# Pulling data from SQL SP in Excel spreadsheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, button, activex

This is an odd one, and I apologise beforehand - I have the below VBA Code in an ActiveX button called 'Refresh':

```
Sub Refresh_Click()

With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Lender Pipeline").OLEDBConnection
.CommandText = "EXECUTE dbo.sp_Lender_Pipeline " & Range("Q2").Value
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Lender Pipeline").Refresh

End Sub
```

What it basically does, is pull data from an SQL SP based on the value of the Q2 cell, and refresh the SP table based on that value - which is a number I manually add in the cell. This number is typically between 1 and 120 (based on IDs within the SP).

The problem:

- It seems to only pull in the data when inputting certain numbers. i.e. 29
- For other numbers, I have to manually click 'Refresh All'.
- If I execute the SP manually in  SQL Server Management, it works perfectly fine, so the problem seems to lie within the VBA.
- If I manually execute the SP from within the Excel spreadsheet, it also works fine...

Does anyone have a clue as to why this may happen? Could it be the VBA, or something else? Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Thank-you.

Comment: Have you run SQL Profiler to make sure that the number parameter is going into the SP as expected, and that the procedure is actually being fired? Is the name and number of return columns consistent regardless of parameter? Maybe SET NOCOUNT ON; It seems as though it would be since a Refresh All seems to work. In Excel 2013, you now have a new checkbox option in the data connection. The new option is whether to refresh a specific connection if a “refresh all” is used. Is this checked? What about the "Refresh automatically when cell value changes" checkbox? Fishing here, but trying to help. :-)

Comment: One thing that will almost always work is to have the SP populate a TEMP table, and base the Excel table on the TEMP table, which gets updated by the SP.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough a colleague of mine had this same issue before.  Tried an assortment of fixes and none appeared to work but rebuilding the workbook in the exact same manner seemed to correct it.

Not the best solution, but it has worked in the past.  If not, try using VBA to call the refreshall command once changing the command text and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your suggestions - It would appear the disabling background refresh in Connection Properties did the trick.